# Providing PointCloud2 data from ZED camera

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, laserscan, ubuntu-xenial, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run a program that requires PointCloud2 data using only the ZED camera, no LASER. Depthcloud to Laserscan is said to work well with ZED, so could I combine this with the Laserscan to Pointcloud routine in one node, would that work? It appears that the latter code isn't really a ROS node but a routine to be included in
another program, correct? The ZED can make Pointcloud output itself but it is too slow, like 2 Hz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283384/providing-pointcloud2-data-from-zed-camera/) by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2018-02-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-23**:
Can you please provide a bit more detail? Where are the LaserScans coming from? A ZED is not a laser scanner, so that confuses me.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-23**:\

> It appears that the latter code isn't really a ROS node but a routine to be included in another program, correct?

the package provides a library, yes, but there are stand-alone nodes as well.

But again: I'm not sure how those could help with what you are asking.

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2018-02-23**:
Sorry that I wasn't clear. I'm talking about the depthimage_to_laserscan node. This takes the Zed output and converts it to laserscan data. Now I'm wanting to convert this laserscan data to PointCloud2 data. You say there is a node for this? I haven't found it, but did find laser_geometry.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-23**:
Would [depth_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/depth_image_proc) not be a more direct route?

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2018-02-23**:
That looks good, I'll study it soon, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found good information on the rtabmap sites! There are tutorials about setup and launch files and video streams.
http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros
I feel sure that I'll be successful with that depth_image_proc and help from rtabmap sites. The abundance of tutorials is very helpful. Thanks to all that have contributed so much to this resource!

---

Originally posted by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) with karma: 299 on 2018-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2018-04-10**:
Stereolabs also has a nodelet on their zed_ros_wrapper repo that runs faster than the node. They also have sample launch files to use them.